# I need help finding out how to prevent my components from exploding (TinkerCad)

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, breadboard, boolean-algebra, protoboard

Basically, I'm making a logic circuit on TinkerCad and I need to turn on a seven-segment display but some of my components explode and I've got no idea how  to solve this.

The components I'm using are:

- 74HC04 NOT
- 74HC11 AND
- 74HC32 OR

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Tip: the illustration you have posted is referred to here as a "cartoon" or wiring diagram. A *schematic* diagram reveals the schema or purpose of the circuit with part numbers and pin designations and is the "language" of circuits. Most of the cartoon generators have schematic export functions although you will need to spend some time laying out the components sensibly and untangling the mess of wires they generate.

Comment: Does TinkerCAD have any debugging information to tell you *why* they exploded?

Comment: The "schematic" is unreadable. The image is so blurry that many of us surely switch to elsewhere in 5 seconds. IC type numbers under the explosions are invisible and there are numerous wires both ends hidden. Do not expect that you can get numerous good explanations.

Comment: Use current-limiting resistors on the LEDs. Using [Current Limiting Resistor Calculator for Leds](http://ledcalc.com/) and 4 mA for the current should help.

Comment: It looks like he has 330 Ohm resistors on the LEDs. Assuming they ARE 330 Ohm it shouldn't cause HC devices to 'explode'

Comment: I would be happy to look at your problem if you post a schematic created in CircuitLab. You can create such a schematic by editing your question and clicking the "schematic" icon. Of course, when you create the schematic in CircuitLab, you can also check the values of things like current and voltage in your circuit. This may allow you to solve your issue yourself.